# Portable Schema Between Derby and DB2

Tags: sql, schema, db2, portability, derby

I'd like to use Derby as a Subset for a given DB2 Database which is meant to run in a Mainframe.

Which tips and tricks would you give when designing the database in order to be at most (at least DML) between the two databases?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that by "at most" you meant "most compatible" in your question?
In general, I think you made the right choice with Derby. It is the only database I know of, that enforces such strong typing as DB2 does. I guess it's not a coincidence that the Derby's version of the `dual` table is called `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`.

The best way to avoid DML incompatibility problems is by using a means of database abstraction in your application. If you are using Java, then [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org) or [jOOQ](http://jooq.sourceforge.net) provide such options. If abstracting your database is not an option for you, then I recommend you write a big set of example queries in an automated integration test. That test, you will then run against both Derby and DB2, to check that the behaviour will be identical (e.g. insert records, read them again using JOINs, nested SELECTS, etc, etc).

As the developer of [jOOQ](http://jooq.sourceforge.net), I can tell you that writing the integration tests yourself will be quite tricky, especially for Derby and DB2! :-)